# Does /dʒ/ exist for words beginning in "D" in AmE?

Tags: american-english

There are quite a few words in BrE beginning with "D" where the initial consonant is pronounced /dʒ/. Think:

- Dew
- Duke

It seems, though, that the pronunciations of these words change in AmE, where /dʒ/ becomes /d/.

Does /dʒ/ exist for words beginning in "D" in AmE?

Comment: Apparently not. IPA phoneme /dʒ/ : https://teflpedia.com/IPA_phoneme_/d%CA%92/

Comment: "Djibouti" -----

Comment: @GregLee You also forgot Pharaoh Djedefre.

Comment: No. We don't confuse *dew* and *jew*, or *duke* and *juke*, even though most Americans pronounce *dew* and *do* the same. They used to be pronounced /dju/ and /djuk/, but that's getting rarer in both the U.S. and the U.K. Quite possibly they're still pronounced "correctly" in Australia.

Comment: That's common in Estuary English uncarefully spoken, but you won't find it in the dictionary. It's like how "Did you eat yet?" often becomes "Juweetchet?" in rapid, familiar discourse, but you won't find it explained that way in any dictionary.

Comment: In AmE we quite often elide *did you* into *d'juh* (dʒʌ): *D'juh finish your homework yet?*